# Unable to Import Yahoo Contacts using (Yahoo API)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, yahoo, import-contacts

I am trying to use Yahoo API to get Contact List of user once authenticated.
Using Yahoo API ( Created token, get GUID) but fail while trying to get Contact List.

Each time I get autheticate URL message.

Comment: Are you running a webserver or is it a client desktop app?

Comment: It will be part of my web application. its webserver.

Comment: Try this documentation: https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/#authorization-code-flow-for-server-side-apps. But basically: if you registered (one time only) your app, you'll need to provide a URL to user click and grant permission to your app. Then Yahoo will give you a code. With this code, your server will ask (using HTTPRequest) for the token. So, only then, using this token, you can call the Contact API.